# Printing specific column to aligned left of space in python

Tags: python

```
print '%7i %4s %13.4f %9.4f %9.4f'%()
```

With this format it prints like this:

```
      1    O        0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

However I want to print just strings aligned to left of 4 space, like this:

```
      1 O           0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: You should try `"%-4s"`.

Comment: oh was that easy, worked well thank you.